# How to filter array within array using key multiple values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```js
const usersLanguageData = {
  transactionId: 6847655349501841000,
  count: 5,
  providerList: [
    {
      code:['US'],
      weekendOfficeHours: false
    },
    {
      code:['US','IND'],
      weekendOfficeHours: true
    },
    {
      code:['US','IND','AUS'],
      weekendOfficeHours: false
    },
    {
      code:[],
      weekendOfficeHours: false
    },
    {
      weekendOfficeHours: true
    }
  ]
};

let filterKeyName1 = ["code"];
let filterValue1 = ['IND','US'];
//let filterValue2 = ['US'];
let filteredProviderData = usersLanguageData.providerList.filter(function(e) {
  return filterKeyName1.every(function(a) {
      console.log(e[a])
      return filterValue1.includes(e[a]);
  });
});

console.log(filteredProviderData);
```

Here the code snippet displays the usersLanguageData into the object form.
Here I want to filter the values with the key say for example here
filterKeyName1 = ['code'] and filterValue1 = ['IND','US'] it will displays the 2nd and 3rd object into the usersLanguageData object.
Same way there is filterValue2 which is into the commented line it will displays the 1st,2nd and 3rd object from the usersLanguageData.

Comment: `filterValue1.includes(e[a])`, if I'm reading this correctly is evaluating to `['IND','US'].includes(usersLanguageData.providerList[#]['code'])`.  But the code in a providerList is an array.  And `array1.includes(array2)` I'm fairly certain is always false.  For instance, if you put `['N', 'D'].includes(['D'])` in the console it resolves to false

Comment: does it makes sense to have a single key in an array and check the values agains, which have in my view to be in another array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `every()` again inside the function. And also make use to check that `e[a]` exists before using `every()` because one of your item doesnot have `code` key

```js
const usersLanguageData = { transactionId: 6847655349501841000, count: 5, providerList: [ { code:['US'], weekendOfficeHours: false }, { code:['US','IND'], weekendOfficeHours: true }, { code:['US','IND','AUS'], weekendOfficeHours: false }, { code:[], weekendOfficeHours: false }, { weekendOfficeHours: true } ] };

let filterKeyName1 = ["code"];
let filterValue1 = ['IND','US'];
//let filterValue2 = ['US'];
let filteredProviderData = usersLanguageData.providerList.filter(function(e) {
  return filterKeyName1.every(function(a) {
      console.log(e[a])
      return e[a] && filterValue1.every(x => e[a].includes(x));
  });
});

console.log(filteredProviderData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter with the value and against the object's property or an empty array.

```js
const usersLanguageData = { transactionId: 6847655349501841000, count: 5, providerList: [{ code: ['US'], weekendOfficeHours: false }, { code: ['US','IND'], weekendOfficeHours: true }, { code: ['US','IND','AUS'], weekendOfficeHours: false }, { code: [], weekendOfficeHours: false }, { weekendOfficeHours: true }] };

let key = "code";
let values = ['IND','US'];
let result = usersLanguageData.providerList
    .filter(o => values.every(v => (o[key] || []).includes(v)));

console.log(result);
```